# Is magento2.4.1 supports the elastic search 7.16.1 version

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch, magento2.4.1

Is magento2.4.1 supports the elastic search 7.16.1 version. please update it

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, Magento 2.4.1 supports the elastic search version 7.7 as per Official site.

You can check more here [System requirements](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements.html)